# When searching for a user, SharePoint prompts for login for mysite

Tags: 2010, my-site, authentication

We are running SharePoint 2010 Server. We have setup mysites on a seperate web application.

Whenever a user searches from our intranet for users, SharePoint will **prompt for login for the data coming from mysites** (the user profiles), until he/she eventually figures out how to get the credentials stored with IE.

Clearly, users can be instructed to store URLs in the IE "Intranet Zone", and also ensure that allow automatic login is enabled. This will allow IE to pass on credentials for the current user. However, it is cumbersome, and we will not succeed in getting all our users to do this.

Would be great, if we could just allow anyone to see everyones picture, without the need for authentication. Anonymous access for the MySite Web app cannot be set up, as far as I can see (option is greyed out).

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you already answered your own question. Cumbersome or not.

Comment: I think not. I'm looking for an easier way, since we will not succeed in getting all our users to follow the cumbersome way.

Comment: (I've update my question - hopefully it is more accurate now.)

Answer (score 3):

If you can use GPO you can push policy to all computers for mysite to be in intranet zone.  Alternatively, you should be able to access mysite without a FQDN.

If neither are acceptable, one trick is to set a startup script to add the AuthForwardServerList reg item to the users computer and add the FQDN to the reg key.  Here is link to KB article, also works like a charm when you have service accounts trying to move files into SharePoint web shares, which is how we found the issue...

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943280

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately our users are not part of a domain, and hence we cannot push by GPO's.
I've tried adding the FQDN as described in the link here, but there's no change. (I've restarted the WebClient service as well, however the KB article describes issues with WebDAV access, which I think is not the case here).